# How to check that a map is linear

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let S be a linear space of step-functions from an interval $[a,b] \to X$ (X is a vectorfield over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $u \in S$.

And the integral Iu = $\sum_i^{n-1} (\xi_{i+1}-\xi_i)u_i$, where $\xi$ is a compatible subdivision with n intervals.

I am to show that the integral is linear, or that this map is linear:

$II:\big( S \to X, u\to Iu\big)$.

The definition (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences)

says that a map, f, is linear if:

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ (additivity)

& $f(x\alpha) = \alpha f(x)$ (homogeneity) (for $\alpha$ in the field, here $\mathbb{R}$, that X,S are the vector fields over.)

But I don't understand how this can be. For $x_1,x_2 \in$ [a,b]; $u(x_1+x_2)$ is generally $\neq u(x_1) + u(x_2)$

Or am I rather supposed to show that for $u,v \in S$: $II(u+v) = II(u) +II(v)$?

I'm a little lost and if anybody could help push me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you not sure of what question you are to answer? I'd guess you need to show $I (u+v)=Iu+Iv$ and similarly the other linearity condition.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're correct. Because I don't see how you can have equality between $u(x+y)$ and $u(x) + u(y)$ (one problem is you can be taken out of the interval u is defined on)